# iPhone: app crash with leak in framework? or is it my fault?

Tags: iphone, crash

I got the following crash logs after my app crashes:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000034f4 objc_msgSend + 20
1   UIKit                           0x000a9248 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 644
2   UIKit                           0x000a8eac -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 44
3   UIKit                           0x0006f480 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1300
4   UIKit                           0x0006ce40 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 200
5   UIKit                           0x00014ab0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 32
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000285ba -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 18
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000a61c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 176
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000a2a4 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 192
9   QuartzCore                      0x00009bb0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 256
10  QuartzCore                      0x000097d8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 276
11  QuartzCore                      0x000119d8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00074244 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00075d9e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 494
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000772f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
17  GraphicsServices                0x00003f88 GSEventRunModal + 188
18  UIKit                           0x00007b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 564
19  UIKit                           0x00005fb8 UIApplicationMain + 964
20  my_app                      0x0000291e main (main.m:14)
21  my_app                      0x000028c8 start + 32
```

or, another times:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00003508 objc_msgSend + 40
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00027348 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
2   UIKit                           0x00009ae4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 276
3   UIKit                           0x00009b04 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 308
4   UIKit                           0x00009b04 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 308
5   UIKit                           0x00009b04 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 308
6   UIKit                           0x00009b04 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 308
7   UIKit                           0x000099bc -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:] + 28
8   UIKit                           0x000095d4 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 448
9   UIKit                           0x00009400 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 28
10  UIKit                           0x0009b788 +[UIViewControllerWrapperView wrapperViewForView:frame:] + 328
11  UIKit                           0x0009e42c -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 140
12  UIKit                           0x0009e38c -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 32
13  UIKit                           0x0009d9d0 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 248
14  UIKit                           0x0009d8c8 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 12
15  UIKit                           0x000b8e54 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 308
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00027348 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
17  UIKit                           0x0008408c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128
18  UIKit                           0x00083ff4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
19  UIKit                           0x000b8c7c -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 416
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00027348 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
21  UIKit                           0x0008408c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128
22  UIKit                           0x00083ff4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
23  UIKit                           0x00083fbc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
24  UIKit                           0x00083c0c -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 528
25  UIKit                           0x000b8acc -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 16
26  UIKit                           0x000b890c -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 108
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00027348 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
28  UIKit                           0x0008408c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 128
29  UIKit                           0x00083ff4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
30  UIKit                           0x00083fbc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
31  UIKit                           0x00083c0c -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 528
32  UIKit                           0x00084484 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 452
33  UIKit                           0x000824e4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 580
34  UIKit                           0x00081b18 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 388
35  UIKit                           0x0007c034 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 444
36  UIKit                           0x0007b7e8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6704
37  GraphicsServices                0x00004edc PurpleEventCallback + 1024
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000742ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
39  CoreFoundation                  0x000761d6 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
40  CoreFoundation                  0x0007718e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
41  CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
42  CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
43  GraphicsServices                0x00003f88 GSEventRunModal + 188
44  UIKit                           0x00007b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 564
45  UIKit                           0x00005fb8 UIApplicationMain + 964
46  my_app                      0x00002ba2 main (main.m:14)
47  my_app                      0x00002b4c start + 32
```

What's wrong there? I mean - my app is at the bottom of the stack trace in the main-method... I checked for memory leaks - nothing...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Based on the first crash stack trace, I would suggest that you have a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320955/what-can-cause-this-sigsegv-error/17184478#17184478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be that something isn't linking correctly in one of you .xib views. Another common cause of this is an object being called upon that's already been released from memory. Try tracing this with `NSZombieEnabled`

Comment: thanks for your reply... the strange thing is that it's only crashing if I change from one tab to another very often; on both views, a table is filled with data from the internet. and if i change very often very quickly, the app crashes suddenly with that stack trace... I think if it's an error in the .xib or a released object, it should crash the first time...

Comment: I had errors very similar to these when I was losing a data because I didn't have a proper retain on it. It was being auto released and when my views would render something based on this data it'd die with similarly cryptic stack traces (because it's not crashing in my code but in the framework side when working with cells).

Comment: I had nearly similar issue when switching views with view controller very fast in an iPad. Yet not found why.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a connection between an xib and its controller.

Comment: ? where do you see that and how can I find out? please also see my comment to the answer from Cosizzle...

Comment: It's just a guess based on having seen similar traces. Based on your comment on the other answer and line 12 of your first trace, I would *guess* that you're trying to call back to a controller that doesn't exist. My first step would be to use viewWillDisappear: and dealloc to clean up anything you might have going on before you switch tabs. Good luck!

Comment: This is very unlikely to be a missing connection in a xib file. If a connection isn't set up, then the @property it sets is nil, and one of two things will happen:

(1) Nothing. Eg tapping a button won't do anything. Trying to send a message (call a method) on a variable or property that is nil does nothing.

(2) An exception will be thrown. In this case the stack trace would have objc_exception_throw on it, and there would be a message giving more details about what happened on the Console.