# app crashing on navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using 2 xib files.  I have a `UIViewController` called `ViewController1` with a hidden Navigation Bar. I have a second xib called `ViewController2` with a visible Navigation Bar. Both are of class `UIViewController`. The second view controller has just one table view.

When I navigate from `ViewController1` (by way of an `IBAction`) that pushes `ViewController2`, the table view loads and works just fine. But when I navigate back to `ViewController1` from `ViewController2` (by way of a back button in the Navigation Bar) the app crashes.

If both xib have their Navigation Bar set to `YES` everything works. I have no idea what's going wrong. Any generic answer to point me in the right direction would be great.

**Here is my crash log: Sure hope I did it right!** And no Im not using storyboards.

```
Incident Identifier: 8B33F4A7-2814-4231-A13C-A462880A885E
CrashReporter Key:   aabab9ba2bbee5087736b75089e1cc49cb5c9a08
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:         Doctoral [5841]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/4FCACD94-E6F3-4E7C-B7CD-E1B6A2916550/Doctoral.app/Doctoral
Identifier:      Doctoral
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-11 11:04:49.091 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf1f9cd48
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c1fc5d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x36757610 _updateViewDependenciesForConstraint + 200
2   UIKit                           0x3675ebd0 __72-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:]_block_invoke_0 + 260
3   Foundation                      0x34ec5994 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 164
4   UIKit                           0x3675ea90 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:] + 92
5   UIKit                           0x36504e50 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 584
6   UIKit                           0x3634d8d0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 52
7   UIKit                           0x3639df3c -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 88
8   UIKit                           0x36334ab6 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 154
9   UIKit                           0x363a98f8 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 44
10  QuartzCore                      0x360e0304 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 204
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c61b5d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3c61ee40 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 224
13  CoreFoundation                  0x344e41ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
14  CoreFoundation                  0x34457238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
15  CoreFoundation                  0x344570c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
16  GraphicsServices                0x38035336 GSEventRunModal + 70
17  UIKit                           0x363732b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
18  Doctoral                        0x00071d18 main (main.m:16)
19  Doctoral                        0x00071ca0 start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6e55d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c620d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c61c374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6e4e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6e4fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x344e52b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344e402c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34457238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x344570c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a456390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c64e0de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c64dfa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6f5d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c643ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6437f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c643680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c6f5d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c643ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c6437f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c643680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x1f9b0400    r1: 0x3679e394      r2: 0x1f5896e0      r3: 0x0000fdff
    r4: 0xf1f9cd40    r5: 0x1f9b0400      r6: 0x36760515      r7: 0x2fd8fba4
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x0d9e78e5     r10: 0x367ddea4     r11: 0x1f5896e0
    ip: 0x3cb76d64    sp: 0x2fd8fb74      lr: 0x36757613      pc: 0x3c1fc5d0
  cpsr: 0x00000030

Binary Images:
   0x70000 -    0x76fff +Doctoral armv7s  <b82e2b945c9f3b8f9a7f5eedab88f169> /var/mobile/Applications/4FCACD94-E6F3-4E7C-B7CD-E1B6A2916550/Doctoral.app/Doctoral
   0x83000 -    0x83fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <a059eb894e623ec09d63294c525ff7a2> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0x9f000 -    0xa0fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <eec9b813adfd3bdf86702ae8bbf0f404> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
   0xc4000 -    0xcffff +Activator.dylib armv7  <5db9a3bf89b73e64be91afc0945c791b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
   0xf6000 -    0xfafff +CydiaSubstrate armv6  <06f99dfff52d306bb188441a8cd33f0b> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/CydiaSubstrate
  0x296000 -   0x2aafff +AdBlocker.dylib armv6  <1405fac00992308ca456962080f0c21c> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
  0x2bf000 -   0x2effff  libpcre.1.dylib arm  /usr/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  0x2f4000 -   0x2f5fff +AdBlockerNetworks.dylib armv6  <8a3aad1966f634d4a0f1cdf58a54efba> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlockerNetworks.dylib
  0x2fb000 -   0x2fcfff +biteSBarClient.dylib armv7  <b42c3a47e8f63b6b9000aa6714694a6d> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/biteSBarClient.dylib
  0x2ff000 -   0x307fff +libstatusbar.dylib armv6  <3d21988042b43fe9b2edd0382d3412f8> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
 0x2ae2000 -  0x2ae6fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7s  <d735e03f72943aa7a3d4ca1b50b6d5df> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fed9000 - 0x2fef9fff  dyld armv7s  <44ac9ef7642f3ba7943f6451887d3af5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3370c000 - 0x3370cfff  Accelerate armv7s  <f4e8c4c464953429ab6bd3160aadd176> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3370d000 - 0x3384afff  vImage armv7s  <49d3cf19d0a23f4d836fc313e5fd6bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3384b000 - 0x33937fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <584e045442be39fc847ffe1a5e4c99b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33938000 - 0x33beefff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <30a3e7dd8c603a9d81b5e42704ba5971> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x33bef000 - 0x33c47fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <936354553eb93d2dafa76ffcad65f9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33c48000 - 0x33c5afff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <5fae8715a0403315bb1991b79677f916> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33c5b000 - 0x33c5bfff  vecLib armv7s  <30275ee8819331229ba21256d7b94596> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x34165000 - 0x3422afff  CFNetwork armv7s  <ef41814d8641319c96cdeb1264d2d150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3422b000 - 0x34281fff  CoreAudio armv7s  <19aa715b19a93a5c8563dbc706e899be> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34295000 - 0x3444dfff  CoreData armv7s  <dee36bfc0c213492983c73d7bd83a27d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3444e000 - 0x34580fff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <bd8e6c9f94b43e3d9af96a0f03ff3011> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x34581000 - 0x346bafff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <ef057fe1c715314cabf133ec26fa718c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x346bc000 - 0x346f7fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <163d7f8309a6350399bbb1fef6cde32c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x348db000 - 0x348f6fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <387d00a9ed55303b8936459a99869e07> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x348f7000 - 0x349acfff  CoreImage armv7s  <7d7cd7998a113ed9b483e7dc9f388b05> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x34a3a000 - 0x34a9ffff  CoreMedia armv7s  <526b25ed6f4e31b790553bd80d46fec7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34b29000 - 0x34b7ffff  CoreTelephony armv7s  <bdf5f32e89073773a7fdbcc87fc6b412> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x34b80000 - 0x34be2fff  CoreText armv7s  <a01bc990cb483e828f7c3e08cd446daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34be3000 - 0x34bf2fff  CoreVideo armv7s  <851591a704dc344aa2fc397094b4c622> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34d77000 - 0x34f3afff  Foundation armv7s  <0f73c35ada563c0bb2ce402d282faefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x350f5000 - 0x3513efff  IOKit armv7s  <4e5e55f27bbb35bab7af348997bfac17> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3513f000 - 0x35317fff  ImageIO armv7s  <e04300f6e6b232ce8a02139d8f18dfdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3582e000 - 0x35887fff  MobileCoreServices armv7s  <b0d1162a8ab03529bb90e416895b568a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x35977000 - 0x3597efff  OpenGLES armv7s  <c9c8f7cbfbe5397382286b878bdf143c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x35980000 - 0x35980fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <b7d1ddfeb0db36d6af7293fa625b12be> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x35984000 - 0x35986fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <8bcac434962435a895fa0b0a3a33b7a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x35987000 - 0x3598bfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <272a9de67f6632c3aebbe2407cfe716b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3598c000 - 0x359cbfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <3a444257935236fab123e46e617c7a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x360cb000 - 0x361dffff  QuartzCore armv7s  <b28fd354be3c38a2965e6368fa35e0c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3622d000 - 0x3625bfff  Security armv7s  <e1fcc8913eba360c868f51558a01cf24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x362da000 - 0x36319fff  SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0fb8d4a2fa8f30ce837e068a046e466b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3631c000 - 0x3686ffff  UIKit armv7s  <222d9eacd99631beacd5f333dae088df> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x36870000 - 0x368affff  VideoToolbox armv7s  <57487f6e3c38304ab0aa14dd16043f5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36b23000 - 0x36b44fff  AccessibilityUtilities armv7s  <6ba5de67ad0c31bb97f83b34643a7dad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
0x36b9d000 - 0x36ba0fff  AggregateDictionary armv7s  <6916a617625e3800bbb75a34294f4d13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36fcc000 - 0x37007fff  AppSupport armv7s  <7d6122cb42363dc981247c926e637a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3707a000 - 0x37083fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <ec78d21573a23c34b6cec05ba56928f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x370b2000 - 0x370c9fff  BackBoardServices armv7s  <36f93cef9f6830f490fe00818bcffa2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x370d3000 - 0x370f7fff  Bom armv7s  <f35bf1c1b24a3742847383801ac37505> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3732d000 - 0x37332fff  CommonUtilities armv7s  <eb0b7e85b57e32f38dc498c0ee97aa7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x375f8000 - 0x375f9fff  CoreSurface armv7s  <55826212d8b4352b87d80f93bc9b25c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x37666000 - 0x3766bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <3b190badb14f3771b353fcd829719c80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x37892000 - 0x378abfff  DictionaryServices armv7s  <27298e235f2c35938e1033517b1196a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3791e000 - 0x37d31fff  FaceCoreLight armv7s  <432cbaeb84743441b9286532bc36c96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x37f29000 - 0x37f35fff  GenerationalStorage armv7s  <4e1afa8de682332ba6a042a6000c636e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x38030000 - 0x3803bfff  GraphicsServices armv7s  <44b33c403523309c9e930818c7fced34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x38327000 - 0x38373fff  IMFoundation armv7s  <55151f53b10934c3a5faac54e354f3f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3837a000 - 0x3837bfff  IOAccelerator armv7s  <832913083f7f347fba1340263ff13b52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x3837c000 - 0x38381fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <828a36a2325738bb8f2d4b97730d253a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x38382000 - 0x38386fff  IOSurface armv7s  <9925fbc4a08d3a17b72ac807cbbba8ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x383d0000 - 0x38577fff  JavaScriptCore armv7s  <f7be721eee903a93a7de361e5627445e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x38872000 - 0x3889ffff  MobileAsset armv7s  <e3217ead58d5390395de360b3ca3a10a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x388e4000 - 0x388e7fff  MobileInstallation armv7s  <7cbe167946123bbea56ae58208e09762> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x388e8000 - 0x388eefff  MobileKeyBag armv7s  <5c7d50e11eb537ae89ea12cb7ddd3935> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3894b000 - 0x3894efff  MobileSystemServices armv7s  <5796fff2895f38e4b0f844269d4fbae5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x39226000 - 0x3924afff  OpenCL armv7s  <87637dacbb3c3e029120369438e96fcf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3985f000 - 0x39887fff  PrintKit armv7s  <7109f645a9ca3a4997b4172aed228723> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x39888000 - 0x398fcfff  ProofReader armv7s  <e391e8d141c5352d978e5fde23afaaad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x39a41000 - 0x39a52fff  SpringBoardServices armv7s  <5b94e9a529753052acde16c21e9d2566> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x39bdd000 - 0x39bdffff  TCC armv7s  <95c2aa492cc03862bd7bbfae6fa62b1b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x39bfe000 - 0x39c0bfff  TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <aa759d908b903f978ab6803b7947e524> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x3a090000 - 0x3a130fff  UIFoundation armv7s  <e3a40cee28653c4485a4918016ff2b8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x3a42c000 - 0x3a44bfff  WebBookmarks armv7s  <ab55332c13da33fd825ea6204338fe19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3a44c000 - 0x3ad7cfff  WebCore armv7s  <f99b83bec11b331ab69194120917a7df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3ad7d000 - 0x3ae59fff  WebKit armv7s  <02c32fdddbdc39b1848b721658a2fa51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3af04000 - 0x3af0bfff  XPCObjects armv7s  <e6846a96a21d382f9fffd6a4536c0aa7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3ba75000 - 0x3ba7bfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <9111bc894a4f3ef683f5ef4d699a861b> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x3ba7c000 - 0x3ba92fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <770ebb2f7d9a35749e6da5d1980c244f> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3baaa000 - 0x3bab6fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <efddaaea8d87321a80d4a6d3f9607a80> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3bac8000 - 0x3bac8fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <12daef214fd234158028c97c22dc5cca> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3bbea000 - 0x3bbf6fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <0f4a8d65b05a364abca1a97e2ae72cb5> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3bbf7000 - 0x3bc00fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <f54b70863d9c3751bb59253b1cb4c706> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3bc01000 - 0x3bc4cfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <3beff5a5233b3f51ab2fc748b68e9519> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3bc4d000 - 0x3bc60fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <f47a5c7bc24c3e4fa73f11b61af635da> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3bc8c000 - 0x3bc8cfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7s  <438a02652cee3aa5aa4729bf696de6e9> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3bc91000 - 0x3bd7efff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <81d6972465103fa3b85b4125f0ad33f1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3bd7f000 - 0x3bec8fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <642482cfc34a3a3b97bd731258dcdc6a> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3bed0000 - 0x3bed0fff  liblangid.dylib armv7s  <ffb53baa33ba3642a55737311f17a672> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3bed3000 - 0x3bedafff  liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <dbd4f278c71b3f219da3e895b1f6ac80> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3c1f9000 - 0x3c2f7fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <1d499765d38c3c8fa92b363f529a02dd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3c3bb000 - 0x3c3d0fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <3f7be9d397d63b8e931d21bd5f49b0eb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3c3f5000 - 0x3c47bfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <758898189dca32a5a19e5200b8952110> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3c47c000 - 0x3c4c8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <249e8ca1717b370287bb556bbd96e303> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3c4c9000 - 0x3c4effff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <96b463f0ffa0344699fce4d48aa623bc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3c4f3000 - 0x3c5a0fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <e87724e212573773a60bc56815cec706> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3c5a1000 - 0x3c5c1fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <c52fbe01ce7b35c799630e97e8f1318b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3c5c2000 - 0x3c5cefff  libz.1.dylib armv7s  <b64a5c1989ba3ba4aafae83d841f9496> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3c5cf000 - 0x3c5d2fff  libcache.dylib armv7s  <911ce99a94623ef1ae1ea786055fd558> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3c5d3000 - 0x3c5d9fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <33140a5fa3fb3e5e8c6bb19bc0e21c5c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3c5da000 - 0x3c5dcfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <cd17f0ee3dbc38f99910d12a6056bf5a> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3c5dd000 - 0x3c5e2fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <5e733170766430eeaa4e7784e3c7555c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3c5e3000 - 0x3c619fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <a15c807dcb003ad69810546a578774d9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3c61a000 - 0x3c62afff  libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <247a388103633e17b24be038eac612c0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3c62b000 - 0x3c62cfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7s  <f873dd712561350096b9452bf1fc4078> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3c62d000 - 0x3c62efff  libdyld.dylib armv7s  <15676e2ee1423f598907ff49fcede85b> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3c62f000 - 0x3c62ffff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <b0a1a911d4853feba44133e9ce499bc9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3c630000 - 0x3c635fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <69dd64aba1413e75967cd4ad0afa2c15> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3c636000 - 0x3c639fff  libmacho.dylib armv7s  <5905b311c6fb376388e56a991bb3193d> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3c63a000 - 0x3c63bfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <b40e964d7c563296b38625bc7082d6a8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3c63c000 - 0x3c63cfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <77a9976b82b73796a0bbc9783929a1e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3c63d000 - 0x3c6c3fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <11bcf1060ec63c8b909a452e6f79be08> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3c6c4000 - 0x3c6cafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <94fab309ed9b35cdbc075cdda221bc70> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3c6cb000 - 0x3c6e3fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <195d8eeb7c3f31bd916c0b5611abc0e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3c6e4000 - 0x3c6fafff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <79bea3ebfda132baba8f5b0ad6ab95f5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3c6fb000 - 0x3c717fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <faafc8292d4935c4a78233e1d0879e13> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3c718000 - 0x3c726fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <137f48e279a83d7496659c8e3d3729d4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3c727000 - 0x3c72efff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <df14146497cb3fa0a002eedbed49da65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3c72f000 - 0x3c730fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <85e91e99abc03db88eddc665424090b4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3c731000 - 0x3c731fff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <3b7ec561dbec3a199f09ea08a64e76ee> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3c732000 - 0x3c747fff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <0562a59bdf8d3f7783e93f35d7e724a8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: in your back button are you dismissing viewcontroller2? You have to properly navigate up and down the view stack or else it'll end up displaying a view that has been popped.

Comment: Update your question with crash log.

Comment: ^ agree. Post your crash log as that will tell you why it's crashing.

Comment: Are you using storyboard to hook these up?

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on from your crash log.  The only obvious thing is that UIKit is trying to send a message to a dealloc'd object. We probably need to see your code that pushes the view controller.  Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: You are sending message to Deallocated object. Enable NSZombie while debugging and see if it catches the deallocated zombie object.

Comment: Also, add an exception breakpoint to catch all exceptions so that the debugger can tell you the exact line of code crashing our app.

Comment: Some general advice for this sort of crash in UIKit can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320955/what-can-cause-this-sigsegv-error/17184478#17184478